# How I can use live surrealdb queries in python

Tags: python, surrealdb

I've tried to use `live()` python method, but the method just returns the uuid of the live query.

Apart of killing the live query using `kill()` I can't figure out how to receive any changes using the official python api like this [rust example](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/blob/8e9bd3a2d6289118a79822a48e2c45541020dfdf/lib/examples/live/main.rs)

Is there any way to use the current version 0.3.2 for live queries?

Thanks in advance,

PS: The non-official pure python [surrealist](https://github.com/kotolex/surrealist) support them, but is synchronous.